# How can I make log4j in groovy resolve class/method names correctly?

Tags: java, groovy, log4j

I'm working on a new Groovy app which uses log4j for logging, but when I use the conversion pattern symbols to insert the class or method name of the caller into the log output, I get the native java class/method names, not the groovy ones. For example:

The conversion pattern

```
"%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} Digitizer: [%p] [%C.%M] %m%n"
```

gives me output like

```
13-07-2012 15:49:30,667 Digitizer: [DEBUG] [org.apache.log4j.Category$debug.call] Environment: dev
```

Clearly, log messages which always tell me the caller was log4j are not useful.

There is a reference to some log4j patch which looks like it might solve this problem on the groovy site at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Logging, but that page has not been updated in well over a year and the link provided there gives a 404.

Does anyone know where I can find this mysterious log4j patch, or of any other way of getting meaningful caller information in my log messages, short of actually hard-coding it into each logger call?

Comment: I seem to remember that info has a performance penalty so people tend to hardcode it into their message text , or get an IDE to do that hard coding

Comment: It does have a performance penalty (at least according to log4j docs), but this is only for debug purposes, and in any case a few ms blocking per message is fine by me for this application. I just want the information it fetches to be correct...

Comment: Ok as long as you know ;). I don't know the location of the log4j patch sorry. I would recommend writing your own appender and using that. Then put a breakpoint on your append method and look up the stack to see if you

Comment: Can access the stack info you want from groovy. Then hard code this logic into your custom appender. Hope this helps, I am no groovy expert so can't help with this much

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there isn't anything out there to do this out of the box so this suggestion is probably as close as I'll get. Will give it a try. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20100724050702/http://www.kotek.net/projects/log4j-groovy

However it is probably not working with the current Version of groovy.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is no longer maintained but at least I can see what's there.